# MODBUS for Python proper referencing

Tags: python, modbus, pymodbus

I'm using pymodbus to attempt to access data on a Morningstar Solar Controller. I have the MODBUS documentation for the controller [here](http://support.morningstarcorp.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/PSMPPT_public-MODBUS-doc_v04.pdf) and it lists where the values are in the registry. I'm really only looking for a few values in the Read Holding Registers (0x03) for the first 15ish addresses. I'm currently using the following code to access data which is reading me back data, but it's completely giberish numbers. If anyone has any advice I'd really appreciate it.

```
from pymodbus.client.sync import ModbusSerialClient as ModbusClient
 
client = ModbusClient(method = 'rtu', port = 'COM1', baudrate = 9600)
client.connect()
 
result = client.read_input_registers(0x003,6,unit=1)
solarVoltage = float(result.registers[0] )
chargingCurrent = float(result.registers[1] )
batteryVoltage = float(result.registers[2] )
batteryTemperature = float(result.registers[3] )
 
# Do something with the data
print(solarVoltage)
print(chargingCurrent)
print(batteryVoltage)
print(batteryTemperature)
 
client.close()
```

Edit: This is the resultant data I get back from reading all 6 registers.
`[0, 17058, 18943, 17662, 18634, 18938, 26098, 8374, 42046, 32768]`

Edit 2: I'm trying to read logical address 5 to 30. So I see what you mean from getting logical address 49, but even changing the read register to `0x0004` still reads out `17056`. I'm not sure if that's an issue with `float16` or reading the wrong address.

Comment: `result.registers[0]` is probably returning the register value as an int16 or like unit=1 indicates, and therefore the value is incorrect and continues to be incorrect after casting to float. It's the first time i see a rare float16 type, i always thought a floating point number is at least 32 bits

Comment: Give me an example of a gibberish number for a given address please.

Comment: This is the resultant data I get back from reading all 6 registers. `[0, 17058, 18943, 17662, 18634, 18938, 26098, 8374, 42046, 32768]` so for example 17058 for the battery voltage

Comment: I wonder if there is a way to unpack `float16` in Python. But obviously, OP's method `float()` can't do that.

Comment: Judging by the instruction manual it looks like you're accessing logical address 49, onwards - is that your intention? First thing I want to check is whether you're actually reading what you think you're reading.

Comment: I'm trying to read logical address 5 to 30. So I see what you mean from getting logical address 49, but even changing the read register to `0x0004` still reads out `17056`. I'm not sure if that's an issue with `float16` or reading the wrong address.